# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody in old phones during runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-httpcomponents

i'm developing an app that upload an image to a server. This is working just fine in new phones but when I run this in a older one I get this error, even with all dependencies added correctly:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody
```

**Note that simple messages that doesn't use multipart post works perfectly.**

This is the phone data:

```
APP_VERSION_CODE=51
APP_VERSION_NAME=2.61
ANDROID_VERSION=4.1.2
PHONE_MODEL=GT-I8190N
```

The gradle config:

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 51
    versionName "2.61"
}


...
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
...

}


dependencies {

...

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

}
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
  HttpClient client = getHTTPClientAC(true);
    HttpPost post = getACPost(url);
    FileBody fb = new FileBody(toUploadFile);
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    //

    builder.addPart("file", fb);
    final HttpEntity yourEntity = builder.build();
    post.setEntity(yourEntity);
```

I've tried using an older version from mimetypes, but it's the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. I changed the apache imports from this:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
```

To this:

```
import com.android.internal.http.multipart.FilePart;
import com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity;
import com.android.internal.http.multipart.Part;
import com.android.internal.http.multipart.StringPart;
```

The code changed to this:

```
    Part[] parts = new Part[1];
    try {
        parts[0] = new FilePart("file", toUploadFile);
        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(parts);
        post.setEntity(multipartEntity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this works fine for new and older phones. I want to punch someone.. thanks!